# Problema con el formato fecha en laravel 9

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

Tengo un inconveniente con una campo donde guardo una fecha, desde javascript esta como cadena(string) y cuando hago un dd controller y trato de ingresarlo a mi BD Mysql me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '29/05/2023' for column

Como podria dar solucion para cambiar de formato se guarde como tipo date en mi BD.

Este es mi codigo en el controller en laravel y el campo start_date viene como cadena al controller.

```
foreach ($actividades as $actividad) {
                
                dd($actividad->start_date);

               
                $activity = Activity::create([
                    'name'          => $actividad->name,
                    'priority'      => $actividad->priority,
                    'start_date'    => $actividad->start_date,
                    'expected_date' => $actividad->expected_date,                    
                    'status'        => $actividad->status,
                    'stage_id'      => $actividad->stage_id,
                    'user_id'       => $user_id   
                ]);

                $activity->projects()->attach((int)$actividad->project_id);              

            }
```

Comment: El tipo de formato correcto de un tipo `DATETIME` para ser guardado en una BD `MySql` con collation  `UTF-8 General Ci` por ejemplo, es: "YYYY-MM-DD Hh:Mm:Ss", debes de agregar una fecha en ese formato *SIN* olvidarte de colocar tambien la hora, si quieres solo guardar una fecha sin horas minutos y segundos entonces no uses un `datetime` si no un tipo DATE.

Comment: Un ejemplo de fecha correcto para guardar en un datetime en la BD seria: `2023-05-28 16:33:01`, y para un `DATE` seria `YYYY-MM-DD` que equivale a `2023-05-28` por ej, basicamente solo tienes que reemplazar los slashes por guiones (`/`) . (`-`).

Answer (score 0):

Podés importar la libería Carbon, y hacer lo siguiente

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

...

foreach ($actividades as $actividad) {
    $activity = Activity::create([
                    'name'          => $actividad->name,
                    'priority'      => $actividad->priority,
                    'start_date'    => Carbon::createFromFormat('DD/MM/Y', $actividad->start_date),
                    'expected_date' => Carbon::createFromFormat('DD/MM/Y', $actividad->expected_date),                    
                    'status'        => $actividad->status,
                    'stage_id'      => $actividad->stage_id,
                    'user_id'       => $user_id   
                ]);

    $activity->projects()->attach((int)$actividad->project_id);              
}
```